# Nodeclipse's CPU utilization is very high

Tags: javascript, eclipse, nodeclipse

I am using Mac (10.10.5) and I already have Eclipse Mars (4.5.2), and now I installed Nodeclipse 1.0.2 with Eclipse Marketplace and created a Nodejs project (reactjs), and then I found the CPU utilization of Eclipse is very high(over 100%).

Can anyone let me know how to fix it? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Raise an issue at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/
and give as much information as possible, e.g. steps you did before and screenshot for a moment when you saw 100% utilization.

It is also strange that you have 100% CPU utilization, as usually PC has 4 cores, so you would see 25% utilization for 1 problematic thread.